# Need to pass a pointer from VB.NET to C++/CLR

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, pointers, c++-cli

I'm trying to create a C++/CLR project to use the SendARP method of IPHlpApi.dll. The function requires a pointer to an array of ULONG variables. I'm not sure how to achieve this or work around it.

**MSDN Information:**

```
DWORD SendARP(
  _In_     IPAddr DestIP,
  _In_     IPAddr SrcIP,
  _Out_    PULONG pMacAddr,
  _Inout_  PULONG PhyAddrLen
);

pMacAddr [out]
A pointer to an array of ULONG variables. This array must have at least two ULONG elements to hold an Ethernet or token ring physical address. The first six bytes of this array receive the physical address that corresponds to the IPv4 address specified by the DestIP parameter.
```

This is what I have in my wrapper class. IPAddr and PULONG are both typedef unsigned long so to get VB.Net to recognise the types I have cast them to ULONG. From what I can tell the other 3 parameters are fine, I just need to change pMacAddr and somehow pass a pointer from VB (or find a work around).

```
ULONG SendARPRequest(ULONG DestIP, ULONG SrcIP, ULONG pMacAddr, ULONG PhyAddrLen) { return ULONG (m_nativeClass->SendARPRequest(IPAddr (DestIP), IPAddr(SrcIP), PULONG(pMacAddr), PULONG (PhyAddrLen))); };
```

If you need any more of my code please ask. I didn't want to fill the post unnecessarily. Thanks in advance.

## EDIT:

**Wrapper.h**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winerror.h>
#include <IPHlpApi.h>
#include "IPHelper.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")


using namespace System;

public ref class NativeClassWrapper {
    IPHelper* m_nativeClass;

public:
    static const ULONG IPH_NO_ERROR = NO_ERROR;
    static const ULONG IPH_ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME = ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME; // The network name cannot be found. This error is returned on Windows Vista and later when an ARP reply to the SendARP request was not received. This error occurs if the destination IPv4 address could not be reached because it is not on the same subnet or the destination computer is not operating.
    static const ULONG IPH_ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW = ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW; // The file name is too long. This error is returned on Windows Vista if the ULONG value pointed to by the PhyAddrLen parameter is less than 6, the size required to store a complete physical address.
    static const ULONG IPH_ERROR_GEN_FAILURE = ERROR_GEN_FAILURE; //A device attached to the system is not functioning. This error is returned on Windows Server 2003 and earlier when an ARP reply to the SendARP request was not received. This error can occur if destination IPv4 address could not be reached because it is not on the same subnet or the destination computer is not operating.
    static const ULONG IPH_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER; //One of the parameters is invalid. This error is returned on Windows Server 2003 and earlier if either the pMacAddr or PhyAddrLen parameter is a NULL pointer.
    static const ULONG IPH_ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER = ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER; //The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation. This error is returned on Windows Server 2003 and earlier if the ULONG value pointed to by the PhyAddrLen parameter is zero.
    static const ULONG IPH_ERROR_NOT_FOUND = ERROR_NOT_FOUND; //Element not found. This   error is returned on Windows Vista if the the SrcIp parameter does not specify a source IPv4 address on an interface on the local computer or the INADDR_ANY IP address (an IPv4 address of 0.0.0.0).
    static const ULONG IPH_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED; //The SendARP function is not supported by the operating system running on the local computer.

public:
    NativeClassWrapper() { m_nativeClass = new IPHelper(); }
    ~NativeClassWrapper() { this->!NativeClassWrapper(); }
    !NativeClassWrapper() { delete m_nativeClass; }

    //DWORD SendARPRequest(IPAddr DestIP, IPAddr SrcIP, PULONG pMacAddr, PULONG PhyAddrLen) { return m_nativeClass->SendARPRequest(DestIP, SrcIP, pMacAddr, PhyAddrLen); };
    ULONG SendARPRequest(ULONG DestIP, ULONG SrcIP, ULONG pMacAddr, ULONG PhyAddrLen) { return ULONG (m_nativeClass->SendARPRequest(IPAddr (DestIP), IPAddr(SrcIP), PULONG(pMacAddr), PULONG (PhyAddrLen))); };

};
```

**IPHelper.h**

```
public class IPHelper {
public:
    DWORD SendARPRequest(IPAddr DestIP, IPAddr SrcIP, PULONG pMacAddr, PULONG PhyAddrLen);  
};
```

**IPHelper.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Wrapper.h"

//DWORD IPHelper::SendARPRequest(IPAddr DestIP, IPAddr SrcIP, PULONG pMacAddr, PULONG PhyAddrLen) {
DWORD IPHelper::SendARPRequest(IPAddr DestIP, IPAddr SrcIP, PULONG pMacAddr, PULONG PhyAddrLen) {
    return SendARP(DestIP, SrcIP, pMacAddr, PhyAddrLen);
};
```

Comment: The reason you create a C++/CLI wrapper class is to make a .Net "Native" interface, hence you would not deal with raw pointers (the C++/CLI code would translate / convert / marshal data). Looks like you want an array of unsigned longs?

Comment: Or, you could just [p/invoke directly](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.sendarp) and skip the C++/CLI.

Comment: I was advised to use C++/CLI as opposed to Interop. I've never done it before but decided to give it a try. I obviously haven't understood how this works. I will add my C++ code to the question. Would you be able to take a look and tell me what I need to do to get the C++ to convert/marshal the data please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [SendARP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358(v=vs.85).aspx) and also the example from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.sendarp), we can write C++/CLI code like this to call it:

```
public ref class NativeClassWrapper
{
public:

    static String^ SendARPRequest(String^ dest, String^ source)
    {
        marshal_context ctx;

        IPAddr DestIp = inet_addr(ctx.marshal_as<const char *>(dest));
        IPAddr SrcIp = inet_addr(ctx.marshal_as<const char *>(source));

        ULONG MacAddr[2];
        ULONG PhysAddrLen = 6;
        memset(&MacAddr, 0xff, sizeof(MacAddr));

        DWORD dwRetVal = SendARP(DestIp, SrcIp, &MacAddr, &PhysAddrLen);

        array<String^>^ str = gcnew array<String^>(PhysAddrLen);
        for (int i = 0; i < PhysAddrLen; ++i)
        {
            str[i] = MacAddr[i].ToString("x2");
        }
        return String::Join(":", str);
    }
};
```

**Note:**

- We don't need to `new` or `delete` some other class, since this is just a function call. This is also why I made the function `static`, so we don't need to `new` this in vb.net.
- I've made the parameters and return values strings (based on usage from the C++ sample and the p/invoke sample)
- I skipped code to test for errors. In this case, you could throw an exception, perhaps.
- I would suggest using an `public enum class` and assign values instead of using individual `static const ULONG`.

Since I don't know much about this function or its use, I have not tested this code, but it should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added error handling to the C++ so I didn't need to pass the error constants to VB any more; but thank you for the enum advice. Your code was returning what looked similar to an IPv6 address. Changing ULONG MacAddr[2]; to BYTE MacAddr[6]; makes it return the correctly formatted MAC address. Would this cause any problems? It hasn't thrown an error so far in a quick test. I'm not sure why but the MSDN information shows PULONG pMacAddr but the IDE is saying it wants PVOID pMacAddr.

Comment: @Daniel no, I don't think that should cause any problems. Like I said, not really familiar with the function itself and just pulled code from the MSDN sample.